# Scripting: Counting users logged in onto the system

Tags: scripting, who

I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Solution script1

who
date +"Today %d %B, there are $# users logged in onto the system"
```

In the background `user1` has logged in onto `tty2` and `tty3` and `root` has logged in onto `pts/0` and `tty1`. The answer then should be

> Today 22 Oktober, there are 2 users logged in onto the system.

Comment: `who | sort -k1,1 -u | wc -l` gives you number unique users logged into system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the output of `who`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

num=$(who | sort -uk1,1 | wc -l)
date +"Today %d %B, there are $num users logged in onto the system"
```

#### Explanation

`sort -uk1,1` : the `-k1,1` means "sort on the 1st field and *only* on the first field". The `-u` means "print only the unique sort fields". Together, they will print one line for each user found.

Piping the above to `wc -l` will print the number of lines which is the number of unique users. Note that `-u` is a GNU extension but since you're using `date -d` which is also GNU, I will assume you are using the GNU versions of the tools.

Comment: As for me to use `awk` in such simple task is too much. `sort` can do it by itself (see my comment above).

Comment: @Costas very good point, I didn't realize the `-u` only applies to the regions set by `-k`. Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Yes, post that as an answer. Then I will check it as best answer.

Comment: The task is simple so better change your aswer if you'd like my proposal.

Comment: Fair enough, done @SanderVanderBorght.